# Spring-Boot REST API can't parse int array

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a simple SpringBoot REST api following hyperskill.org's "Web Quiz Engine" project.

But the Solve endpoint refuses to work.

Here's the controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
@Validated
public class QuizController {

  //snip

  @PostMapping(value = "/quizzes/{id}/solve")
  public Result solveQuiz(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody int[] answer){
    return quizService.solveQuiz(id, answer);
  }
}
```

Here's my postman :
[stackoverflow disallows embedding images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A245J.png)

POST http://localhost:8889/api/quizzes/1/solve?id=1

Body *raw

```json
{
 "answer": [2]
}
```

And the error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `[I` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `[I` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)

I get the same error when I run the provided tests. Everything works until it try's to call Solve. What's most confusing is the type `[I`.  What is going on?

Edit: Tried to follow the answer below:

```java
  @PostMapping(value = "/quizzes/{id}/solve")
  public Result solveQuiz(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody AnswerArray answer){
    return quizService.solveQuiz(id, answer.getAnswers());
  }
```

and AnswerArray:

```java
@Data
public class AnswerArray {
  @NotNull
  private List<Integer> answers;
}
```

Now the error is:

> Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A245J.png) in public engine.Entities.Result engine.Controller.QuizController.solveQuiz(java.lang.Long,engine.Entities.AnswerArray): [Field error in object 'answerArray' on field 'answers': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.answerArray.answers,NotNull.answers,NotNull.java.util.List,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [answerArray.answers,answers]; arguments []; default message [answers]]; default message [must not be null]] ]

I also tried AnswerArray with an int[] and an Integer[] and also got null values. What am I missing?

Comment: For background, take a look at [this JSON overview](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), especially the section describing how "_JSON is built on two structures_". You will see your JSON is an object (which contains an array) - but it is not itself an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you are not posting an `int[]`

this is your body:

```
{
    "answer": [
        2
    ]
}
```

Which is actually a `Object` containing a `list` of `integers`

so your Java object should look as follows:

```
// The class can be named whatever
public class Request {
    
    private List<Integer> answer;

    // constructor

    // getters and setters
}
```

And the function should look like:

```
public Result solveQuiz(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Request answer){
    return quizService.solveQuiz(id, answer.getAnswer());
}
```

Comment: While this does settle what format the json corresponds too, it doesn't actually solve my problem, please see my edit

Answer (score -2):

The int[] does need to be inside a class, but the other answer left out a critical bit of information: that class needs a no-arg constructor that has an empty body.  The default constructor works, but if you add an explicit constructor (or use Lombok's @Data), you no longer get the default. So adding a default constructor seems to be what I ultimately needed (by use of adding Lombok's
@NoArgsConstructor).  Although I had tried that before, but Spring's lack of useful error info caused me to abandon it when there was another problem simultaneously.

In summary solveQuiz needed the int[] wrapped in an object. And that object needs an empty no-arg constructor (or default constructor), and Getter and Setter. (or Lombok @NoArgsConstructor)

So Here's my wrapper object:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AnswerArray {
  @NotNull
  private int[] answer;
}
```

and my api function:

```java
  @PostMapping(value = "/quizzes/{id}/solve")
  public Result solveQuiz(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid @RequestBody AnswerArray answer){
    return quizService.solveQuiz(id, answer.getAnswer());
  }
```

The problem may also be intellij not correctly compiling the changes, A "Rebuild Project" might have ultimately been the fix.